# How do I animate UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage: forBarMetrics:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I am changing the background image of the navigation bar when a certain controller is pushed. I want to animate that change. I can do so with the following code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.navigationBar
                  duration:0.3f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"now-playing-nav-bar.png"]
                                                 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
} completion:NULL];
```

However, this blocks the default push animation applied to the `navigationBarTitle` and `UIBarButtonItem`s.

How do I  get the background change and the push animations to work together?

I would prefer as vanilla a solution as possible.

PS: I can't use `tintColor` because the background is textured.

Comment: What happens if you set the backgroundImage in the `viewWillAppear:` of the new view controller?

Comment: @BenjaminMayo The transition animation works properly but the push animation doesn't.

Comment: Get rid of the transition block and just change the backgroundImage. Does that help?

Comment: @BenjaminMayo That does not animate the backgroundImage. It just appears.

Comment: @BenjaminMayo I found a solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Tested only on iOS 6**

I solved it using Core Animation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 0.3;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"now-playing-nav-bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }];
}
```

Do the same in `viewWillDisappear:` and you are good to go.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not a good place to perform animations. It's called when `UIViewController`'s `view` is lazily loaded.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic It's an old answer, I was quite a beginner. I'm not even using block animations. Will update it soon. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: Upvoted. By the way, why `CATransition` instead of high-level `transitionWithView`? Also, why not inherit animation duration and options so that it works properly with interactive pop, etc.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic Read the question. `transitionWithView` didn't work. And this answer was for iOS 6, when there was no interactive pop. I think animating that would require `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

Comment: Just tested the code on iOS7 and iOS8, the code works, and interactive pop automatically works with that, great!. However, the `UIView` animation API is not needed.

Comment: @zannnennkunn Great! I'd appreciate it if you could edit the answer to include the version that works.

Comment: @duci9y Edited. There is one caveat with the code and I have not looked into that yet (`UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` is probably the right place to look at) : start an interactive pop, then cancel the pop, then, the nav bar will perform the animation in `viewWillDisappear` first, followed by the animation in `viewWillAppear`. Other than that, the code works well with push, pop, interactive pop (as long as you don't cancel the pop). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**This works for me on iOS 9:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    changeNavigationBackground()
}

func changeNavigationBackground() {
    // navigationBar should always exist if the view controller is in a UINavigationController
    guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }

    // the current navigation background
    guard let imageView = navigationBar.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIImageView }).first else { return }
    let image = UIImage(named: "navigation_background")
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    newImageView.frame = imageView.frame
    newImageView.alpha = 0.0
    navigationBar.insertSubview(newImageView, belowSubview: imageView)

    transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context) in
        imageView.alpha = 0.0
        newImageView.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { (context) in
        newImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        imageView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

I try to avoid Core Animation if possible, so I only used views and changed their alpha values alongside the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Is the push animation work or not without the transition animation? If yes, probably you need to do the push animation yourself in the block of changing navigation bar's image.